# The view awesomeinventory.supplier.views.supplierCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead in Create view

Tags: django

My code is:
views.py

```
class supplierListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = "supplier/Supplier_list.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        organisation = self.request.user.userprofile.company
        return Supplier.objects.filter(organisation=organisation)

class supplierCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "supplier/supplier_create.html"
    form_class = SupplierModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("supplier:supplier_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        supplier = form.save(commit=False)
        supplier.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile.company
        supplier.supplier_created_by = self.request.user
        supplier.save()
```

my urls:

```
from awesomeinventory.supplier.views import (
    supplierListView,
    supplierDetailView,
    supplierCreateView,
    supplierContactListView,
    supplierContactCreateView,
    supplierContactDetailView,

)

app_name = "supplier"
urlpatterns = [
    path("supplier_list/", view=supplierListView.as_view(), name="supplier_list"),
    path("supplier_create/", view=supplierCreateView.as_view(), name="supplier_create"),
    path("<int:pk>/detail/", view=supplierDetailView.as_view(), name="supplier_detail"),
    path("<int:pk>/update/", view=supplierDetailView.as_view(), name="supplier_update"),
    path("<int:pk>/delete/", view=supplierDetailView.as_view(), name="supplier_delete"),

    path("supplierContact_list/", view=supplierContactListView.as_view(), name="supplierContact_list"),
    path("<int:suppk>/supplierContact_create/", view=supplierContactCreateView.as_view(), name="supplierContact_create"), # int is supplier_id
    path("<int:pk>/Contact/detail/", view=supplierContactDetailView.as_view(), name="supplierContact_detail"),
]
```

I m able to go to supplier:supplier_list page and it works well.

But when I want to create a supplier with supplierCreateView, supplier is create but it seems to have an issue with get_success_url as I have error
The view awesomeinventory.supplier.views.supplierCreateView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `form_valid` is supposed to return the response or redirect the user. In your implementation you only save the object and return nothing essentially returning `None` which gives you an error. Instead of using `form.save(commit=False)` you can simply modify the `instance` wrapped by the form and leave all the processing to the super classes `form_valid`:

```py
class supplierCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "supplier/supplier_create.html"
    form_class = SupplierModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("supplier:supplier_list")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.organisation = self.request.user.userprofile.company
        form.instance.supplier_created_by = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

> **Note**: A class name should ideally be in `PascalCase` so `SupplierCreateView` instead of <s>`supplierCreateView`</s>

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you.

```py
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class supplierCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = "supplier/supplier_create.html"
    form_class = SupplierModelForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        # pay attention I'm using reverse_lazy instead of reverse
        return reverse_lazy("supplier:supplier_list")
```

You can read more about [reverse_lazy here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy)

Comment: `reverse_lazy` would give an error if used in `get_success_url`. Normally when we don't override `get_success_url` it tries this `str(self.success_url)` to make sure the url it returns is a string.